Zoom is working but invisible when ubuntu reboot
uname -a gives
Linux ubuntu 6.8.0-40-generic #40~22.04.3-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jul 30 17:30:19 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Zoom version 6.2.3 (2056)
I removed the previous version of zoom snap and installed latest version from .deb file. Zoom worked as usual, great.
But after rebooting the machine it seemed not work, neither by clicking the shortcut nor by typing zoom in the terminal. But its in the job list. Its invisible! I killed them all zoom processes and started it again then it worked great as usual. After reboot it did this behaviour again. Zoom is not in the "startup programs" list.
Anyone had experience like this? Thank you.
EDIT: Because of screen sharing didnt work properly I removed latest version and back to snap one. Everything is fine now. Seems i wont struggle with it. Someone said to me that "if it works, dont touch it". But if anyone drop the suggestions for latest version of zoom related to my problems it will be appriciated and i will try again with latest version.

In what way does it not work when you type zoom in terminal?

I have not had this exact issue, but I have run into other ones with Zoom. What fixed it for me was to remove all of the config files in my home directory, then relaunch Zoom.
This is where they are located on my system, running the .deb version. Please review first to make sure it is the same on yours, and make sure Zoom is not running first.
rm ~/.config/zoomus.conf
rm -r ~/.zoom


Thank you for your time. I tried it but same thing.
